# Probability of opening 3 doors in 3 moves

Tags: probability

I have 3 doors closed, one move changes the state of the door (opened or closed). The probability is said to be 2/9. Opening 1 door has a probability of 1, opening another door has a probability of 2/3 since the first one is already opened, opening the last closed door has a probability od 1/3, resulting to 2/9.

I tried a new method where I assigned each door a letter, a,b,c. Let x,y,z be the number of moves I spend on a,b,c respectively. Then $x+y+z = 3$ and the number of ways is 10 by stars and bars. All the doors will open if it has an odd number of moves. There is only 1 posibility which is (1,1,1). thus the probability is 1/10.

Which solution is correct and why is the other one wrong

Answer (score 2):

If the doors are chosen uniformly at random, and each choice is independent of the previous choices, then there are $3^3 = 27$ unique sequences of $3$ moves.  Of these, there are $3! = 6$ sequences in which each door is chosen exactly once, thereby each door is opened when the initial state of each door is closed.  Therefore, the probability in which all three doors are opened at the end of $3$ moves is $6/27 = 2/9$, as in your first solution.

The second solution is incorrect because, although it is true that the number of ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying $x + y + z = 3$ is $10$, it is not true that each such triple occurs with equal probability, which is what you are implicitly assuming when you say the only elementary outcome for which all three doors end in the open state corresponds to $(1,1,1)$, hence the probability is $1/10$.  You can see this immediately by observing that the outcome $(3,0,0)$ can only happen with probability $1/27$, whereas the outcome $(1,1,1)$ can occur from selecting the sequence $(a,b,c)$, or $(b,c,a)$, or $(c,a,b)$, etc.

This is a common mistake, much in the way that when we toss a fair coin twice, the outcome $(H, T)$ is distinct from $(T, H)$, hence the probability of one head and one tail is not $1/3$ but $1/2$.